# Removing Ring Towel holder

Tags: bathroom, screws, bathroom-fixtures

[image: Screw]

[image: Screw]

How can I remove this ring towel holder? The Screw inside looks warped and stripped, there is absolutely nothing to grab onto. Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What happens to the holder after?  Is it put back on or replaced with a new one/removed completely?  Might be able to drill it out, but looks like a bad place.

Comment: Have you tried a variety of hex keys? If you find one that just fits, but doesn't seem to grab, bang it in with a hammer. If it still won't grab, go to the next larger size in your set and bang that in. Hit it hard enough and it should drive itself in deep enough to hold for one-time use

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic solution.  You can try to drill out the screw, but being underneath it will have it's own set of difficulties.

There are 2 alternatives:

1:  Just rip the ring from the wall. There will be damage that will need to be repaired. How much? how bad?..is an unknown.

2:  Drill some larger, 1/2" holes in the holder above and below the ring post. These holes will hopefully give access to the screws holding the item to the wall. Remove the screws and you're done.  If you cannot axcess the screws with just 2 holes drill more until you can.

Both solutions are time consuming either in action or repairs. My choice would be #2.